# Azure Function calls from Logic App fails with error in Azure Portal and not in local debugging environment

Tags: azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, serverless

Came across an extremely weird issue in Azure Functions in Azure Portal. The Azure Function in my case has an `JSON` input with HTTP endpoint having POST operation. Apparently the Azure Function fails at runtime with below error:

> BadRequest. Http request failed as the content was not valid: 'Unable to translate bytes [93] at index 73 from specified code page to Unicode.'.

When we debug the Azure Function locally with the same `JSON`. It works without an issue.
[Azure Function Error in Azure Portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXiMC.jpg) 
[Successful Postman request debugging locally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3IJH.jpg)

After analyzing the `JSON` data I could pinpoint the issue and it was with Special Characters "" in `JSON` data after a liquid map transformation but apparently we cannot replicate such errors in Azure Function locally. Why is that so? Why two different behavior in Azure portal and local debugging environment with same `JSON` body and headers?

[LogicApp DesignView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DquEA.jpg)

Comment: Hi AbhiShetty, may I know how did you input the json data to your function in your logic app ? Could you please provide a screenshot of this part in your logic app ?

Comment: And may I know which "Runtime stack" did you choose for your function? .net core ?

Comment: Hi @HuryShen , I am currently using Dot Net Runtime, Probably older version Runtime version: 1.0.12854.0 (~1)

Comment: Editing the Question to incorporate the Screenshot of Design view of Logic App.

Comment: Hi AbhiShetty, may I know if your problem was solved ?

Answer (score 0):

In my test, the function connector in logic app will do escape operation automatically(if the input is string), so I think we do not need to worry about the double quotation marks. But in you logic app, I saw you put the content from "Transform JSON to JSON" to "jsonData" field in the request body of your function, in my test it may cause error. Could you please have a try with the solution below:

Convert the content from "Transform JSON to JSON" to string and then put it to the request body in your function connector.
[image]

Please have a try.

Comment: The method suggested by you helped to escape some special characters within Azure Function JSON body but it didn't solve the different behaviour problem. The newly generated JSON data after applying String() expression failed with the same error in Azure Portal but same JSON works in Local Debugging environment using Visual Studio and Postman.Apparently it seems the Function APP is not able to throw the error locally.

Comment: The Bug related to Escape Sequence got resolved when i made following changes in Liquid Maps to filter out Special Characters:
Earlier i was using "| StripHtml | Escape" liquid Maps Filter and i had to change it to "| StripHtml | EscapeOnce ".This filtered out escapeCharacters only once if it was already done.

After making above change the spl chars content changed from :
"GuidelineData": "&amp;#xa0;&amp;#xa0;Completing "
to "GuidelineData": "&#xa0;&#xa0;Completing " 

But my original query as to why such issues cant be reproduced locally remains open.